# Download a series of generated files one after another without using any js timeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, download

Basically, I have a python script that returns as :

```
response = HttpResponse(zip_file.read(), 
content_type="application/epub+zip")
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="'+ slugify(node_obj.name) + '.epub"'
return response
```

On front-end, I display a series of anchor tags, each having a link to create and download a file and all these elements have common class.
Also, there is a provision to create and download all files, which does javascript job of looping over all the above anchor tags and triggers the click event after a specific timeinterval.

However, the time taken for generation of each file differs. Hence, `setInterval` and `setTimeout` does not apply.

Setting a cookie and periodically checking the downloadComplete flag too is not working as said in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download).

Comment: Can you provide more details? Where the downloaded files are saved?

Comment: The mentioned response downloads the file automatically at client's machine. they are not saved on server.